# Access https site using SAS package

Tags: https, sas

I want to access a https site by providing credential information such as username and password using SAS DS2 HTTP package. Can anyone please provide the code snippet ? I tried adding to the request header but it is not working. Thanks in advance.

```
        declare package http h();
        h.createGetMethod(url);

        h.addRequestHeader('WEBUSERNAME', 'username');
        h.addRequestHeader('WEBPASSWORD', 'password');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WEBUSERNAME`/`WEBPASSWORD` are method used by `proc http`. As far as I know they are not standard http header requests. For credentials you will need authorization. Something like:

```
auth =  put('user:pass',$base64x64.);
h.addRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic '||auth);
```

Can you not just use the `filename url` statement?

Answer (score 0):

"Thanks Jetzler". I am using like below and it works !

```
        h.createGetMethod(url);

        auth =  put('username:Password',$base64x64.);
        h.addRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' || auth);

        h.executeMethod();

        status = h.getStatusCode();
        put 'Requested resource for country code:' code 'executeMethod() status:' status;

        if status eq 200 then
            do;
                /* 200 = OK */
                /* retrieve the body from the response that came from the server */
                h.getResponseBodyAsString(body, rc);
            end;

        return body;
```